# Extended-to-duplicate monitor script without function key

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I would like to create a bash script that allows me to:

change the mode of my screen from extended to duplicate and vice versa.

My keyboard does not have the function key and I would like to create a script that will cut me off this operation, but I do not know how to do it

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share the output of this command `xrandr --current`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formulate your bash function, you first need to know the connected screens with this command.

```
xrandr --current
```

It will show you an output similar to this

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1600 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 210mm
   1600x900      60.04*+  59.82    39.99
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85
   1280x800      59.81    59.91
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74
   1024x768      60.00
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.32    56.25
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57
   800x450       60.00
   640x480       59.94
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see, I have 2 outputs `eDPI1` (My laptop screen) and `HDMI1` my external monitor that is currently disconnected.

With these variables, I can now write a function that toggles from mirror to extend and back.

```
#!/bin/bash

export SCREEN_STATE="extended"

function screenToggle() {
    if [[ $SCREEN_STATE == "extended" ]]; then
        xrandr --output eDPI1 --output HDMI1 --same-as eDPI1
        export SCREEN_STATE="mirrored"

    else
        xrandr --output eDPI1 --output HDMI1 --left-of eDPI1
        export SCREEN_STATE="extended"

    fi
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code and on the first run, the displays will go to mirror mode due to the second line and you can't change that behaviour.

For more values that you may need to pass to control the resolution see `man xrandr` and [this similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/371793/179647).